# Sorting versions in multidimensional list python

Tags: python

I have a list that is names of modules and versions. I have to sort it by version. Now, sorting a list that has only versions is pretty straightforward, ie.

strVers.sort(key=LooseVersion)

But what if I have 2 dimensional list?
i.e.

```
['app1', '1.0.0']
['app1', '1.0.1']
['app2', '1.0']
['app2', '1.1']
```

etc.

how do I do the same and have both columns sorted? Sorting 2 dimensional array is no problem too with "sorted", but I need to use LooseVersion?

Thanks

Comment: What type of object is `app1`, `app2`, ... and how do you expect them to be sorted? Do you want to sort by app first and then by version or the other way around?

Comment: it is a list, and yes, I need by app and then by version.

Comment: I know that you have a list. I need the datatype of `appX`. Are these strings or what (same goes for your version numbers)?

Comment: aha, strings, yes. just app names...

Comment: is this problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2:

```
yourlist.sort(key=lambda (name, version): (name, LooseVersion(version)))
```

Python 3

```
yourlist.sort(key=lambda name_version: (name_version[0], LooseVersion(name_version[1])))
```

Comment: Thanx, this looks simple and uses LooseVersion, will try!